# Grab words before and after a matched term

Tags: python, regex

I'm taking my first steps with Python and I have a problem to solve in which I need regex.

I'm parsing several lines of text and I need to grab 5 words before and after a certain match. The term to match is always the same, and lines can have more than one occurrence of that term.

```
r"(?i)((?:\S+\s+){0,5})<tag>(\w*)</tag>\s*((?:\S+\s+){0,5})"
```

This works in very specific situations: if there's only one occurence of the term between tags (or if they are well-spaced between them), and if there are enough words before the first occurrence.

The problem is:

1 - if a second occurrence is within the +5 range of the first occurrence, there are no -5 for the second, or the second just becomes engulfed by the first. Overlapping problem?

2 - if there are less than 5 words, or if you up the range to 7 or 8, it just skips the first occurrence to the second or third.

So a line that's something like:

```
word word word match word word match word word word
```

Would not be parsed well.

Is there a way to take into account these issues and make it work?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Would you please provide a few examples of test string?

Comment: IS regex your only option. Python can split strings into a list which you can then iterate over.

Comment: @Chih-HsuJackLin for instance:
"Hello my name is Steve. I have another friend named Steve but I'm the best Steve around. Steve rules."
If i wanted to match 'Steve' and grab at least 5 words after and before evey match, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest, I honestly don't know. Thought regex was the easiest way to do it. What are you thinking exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what your after - without using regex

```
#!/usr/bin/env python



def find_words(s, count, needle):

  # split the string into a list
  lst = s.split()

  # get the index of the where the needle is
  idx = lst.index(needle)

  # s is the start and end of the list you need
  s = idx -count
  e = idx +count

  # print the list as slice notation
  print lst[s:e+1]


def find_occurrences_in_list(s, count, needle):
  # split the string into a list
  lst = s.split()

  idxList = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == needle]

  # print idxList

  r = []
  for n in idxList:
    s = n-count
    e = n+count
    # append the list as slice notation
    r.append(" ".join(lst[s:e+1]))

  print r

# the string of words
mystring1 = "zero one two three four five match six seven eight nine ten eleven"
# call function to find string, 5 words head & behind, looking for the word "match"
find_occurrences_in_list(mystring1, 5, "match")

# call function to find string, 3 words head & behind, looking for the word "nation"
mystring2 = "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation conceived in Liberty and dedicated to the proposition"
find_occurrences_in_list(mystring2, 3, "nation")

mystring3 = "zero one two three four five match six seven match eight nine ten eleven"
find_occurrences_in_list(mystring3, 2, "match")


['one two three four five match six seven eight nine ten']
['continent a new nation conceived in Liberty']
['four five match six seven', 'six seven match eight nine']
```

Comment: It's a good way, however it can be interesting to use a regex to split the string on word boundaries or on non-word characters to make this script useful in real life. *(I suspect the final goal is to extract an excerpt around a specific word)*

Comment: It's an elegant solution without regex! However, it still leaves me with the same problem. Doesn't work for multiple matches inside the same string, and if you choose a bigger capture range than the existing number of words...

Example:
    mystring1 = "zero one two three four five match six seven match eight nine ten eleven"

For:
    find_words(mystring1, 8, "match")

Any workaround on that...?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes, the goal is to extract a predetermined range of words (no more than 5 or 6). Can my regex be used with boundaries to make it work?

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest thank you, I'm going to work from your solution! Only one thing missing though. Do you have a way to guarantee that if you don't have enough words on the 'before', it captures the maximum existing amount? Right now, if you put '7' on mystring3, it returns 'eleven'. '8' returns 'ten eleven'.

An excess of words on the 'after' works, it just stops at the end of the list.

Comment: @DJM I did think of that but didn't include it - I'm sure you can  it out ;)